# Specific heat and latent heat of transformation in superconductors

Tags: superconductivity

We know that the specific heat of a superconductor at the transition point (when H=0) is discontinuous. So, the superconductor receives heat without changing temperature. On the other hand, from the Clapeyron equation we know that the latent heat of transformation is zero when there is no magnetic field. Also, the latent heat of transformation represents the quantity of heat that the system receives when it passes from superconductor to normal state.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

> We know that the specific heat of a superconductor at the transition
>   point (when H=0) is discontinuous. So, the superconductor receives
>   heat without changing temperature.

A discontinuity in the specific heat does not imply that the material has a latent heat. Imagine you have 1 kg of material which has some constant specific heat of, say, 1 J/(kg ˚C) below a transition which jumps discontinuously to 2 J/(kg ˚C) at and above the transition. For every Joule of heat energy that you put into the object below the transition, its temperature will increase by 1 ˚C. Once you reach the transition, you will instead have to put in 2 Joules of heat energy for every 1 ˚C temperature rise in the object. But that's it. There's no latent heat associated with the transition. The temperature will never pause as you're putting more heat energy into the object.

Comment: I was thinking that the temperature will pause as we are putting more heat energy. Thanks.

Comment: @user201949 - I think that a singularity in the specific heat where the specific heat shoots up towards infinity at a transition is often (but not always) associated with a non-zero latent heat and a 1st-order phase transition. That's different from a mere discontinuity in the specific heat like in the example I described.